# Removing overlapping features by percentage in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, overlapping-features, linestring

I have geometry records of type `MultiLineStringZM` and I am trying to `INSERT` new records that overlap some of the records currently in the table. If they were type `MultiPolygon` I could use `ST_Area()` as in the following

```sql
SELECT
    a.id
FROM
    a, b
WHERE
    ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) > 0.5 * ST_Area(a.geom);
```

to identify the polygons that overlap by a majority. However `ST_Area()` is not a compatible function for `MultiLineStringZM`, and the above query does not return any results.

`ST_Covers()`, `ST_Within()` & `ST_Intersects()` will either not return any results or return too many depending.

How can I identify & delete all records overlapped by a 'majority' or some specified fraction for this geometry type?

Comment: Are the lines perfectly covering each others (where they overlap), or is there a tolerance to consider?

Comment: if like you said st_area is not compatible with MultiLineStringZM then try using the ST_Force_2D to convert the geometries to 2D

Comment: and then convert to 4D? St_Area(ST_Force2D(geom))? Is any information lost by doing so?

Comment: @JGH they do not most of the time, but do directly overlap the lines > 40-50%

Comment: Did you try ST_Length? Only works when the coordinates of the lines are perfectly aligned, as @JGH mentioned.

Comment: @DonaldPeat ST_AREA() from my knowledge will only return the area of of a 2D cartesian plane and I have not come across a 3D or 4D st_area function.

Comment: St_Area(ST_Force2D(geom)) will only give you back the area in 2D. to your question "is any information lost?" it depends what you mean lost. since you are only selecting a.id from your query, the only thing you are "losing" is the 3d and 4d measurements in your where statement.

Comment: if you wanted to bring along one of the geometries in the select statement, they would still be in 4D because you are only applying the st_force2D on the fly in the where statement

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DArea.html check this function out

Comment: If your lines overlap only at a point then there is no way you can compare by a percentage. A simple ST_intersects() should tell you. If your lines generally intersect over a great percentage of their length, then you could use ST_Lenght() or make a small buffer around each of them in the ST_Intersection() and still use the percentage of ST_Area() for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, which finds the intersection and calculates the total length of the intersection, then compares that to the line length.  Change the tolerance as needed (I'm assuming you want less than 50% overlap):

```
select id from 
  (select 
    a.id,
    st_length(st_union(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))) ilen,
    st_length(geom) len
  from
    a,
    (select st_union(geom) geom from b) b
    group by a.id
  ) foo 
where ilen/len < 0.5;
```

If you also need to account for an intersection tolerance (if lines are less than 1 m apart, is that still an intersection?), you can use buffers and st_area to determine overlap %.  I'm assuming your srid is lat/lon.  If it's projected, you don't need the geography casting.

```
select id from 
  (select 
    a.id, 
    st_area(st_union(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))) iarea,
    st_area(geom) area
  from 
    (select id, st_buffer(geom::geography,1)::geometry geom from a) a,
    (select st_union(st_buffer(geom::geography,1)::geometry) geom from b) b
    group by a.id
  ) foo 
where iarea/area < 0.5;
```